# Multiple PPTP VPN Client on Cisco 3G Router

Tags: router, vpn, pptp, 3g

I want the router to be a client to 2 independent PPTP servers, both are in different cities in Cisco routers. I have tested with one on cisco 1841 aqnd its working fine; but when I add the 2nd, its using vpdn-group 1 and therefore connecting to the wrong PPTP server:

here is the config for the one that works:

vpdn-group 1
request-dialin
protocol pptp
rotary-group 0
initiate-to ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

!
interface Dialer0
mtu 1450
ip address negotiated
ip pim dense-mode
ip nat outside
ip virtual-reassembly
zone-member security private
encapsulation ppp
ip igmp query-interval 125
dialer in-band
dialer idle-timeout 0
dialer string 123
dialer vpdn
dialer-group 1
no peer neighbor-route
no cdp enable
ppp pfc local request
ppp pfc remote apply
ppp encrypt mppe auto
ppp authentication ms-chap-v2 ms-chap eap chap pap callin
ppp eap refuse
ppp chap hostname xxx@xxx
ppp chap password 7 xxxpassword

But if I create a vpdn-group 2 and a Dialer1 interface, with dialer-group 2, its still attempting to connect to the IP in vpdn-group 1 - how do I get it to use the 2nd vpdn-group, or how do I make this work? and which cisco 3G Router you prefer because these are remote sites and only 3G Internet service is available.

Comment: Here the problem is one of routing table. You cannot have both VPNs access all sites, you must tell your system which system you wish to connect via the first, an which to connect to via the second one. In principle, you can also use each VPN to contact only the two LANs, and using your own gateway to contact everybody else. Or any mixture of these solutions at will. The important point though is to study your own routing table, and act on that.